# Style a custom HTML module

Tags: joomla-3.x, css, custom-module

So, I have worked up a html menu with a css3 hexagon grid that I'm adding to a page with a custom html module. Can I add a separate style sheet for this module? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Mikan although if you really want to add a separate stylesheet there are at least a couple of ways to do this:

1. add some code to your custom HTML module as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/20607027/1983389 using the free or paid version of [Sourcerer](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/sourcerer) or similar.
2. use a third party extension like the free or paid version of [EasyScript](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/easyscript) or similar

Comment: thanks @neil, I accepted this answer because it contained a solution, even though it's better not to.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to add separate CSS file. You can just style-up new selectors you want, or use some existing in main `template.css` or `custom.css`, whichever you are using, and reference them in Custom HTML module.

That also goes along the line of general guidelines of using as small naumber of external CSS/JS files as possible, in order to reduce number of HTTP requests.

Comment: appreciated @mikan

Comment: You're quite welcome :)

Comment: You dont need to reference the `custom.css` file. If it has any styling in it, it's automatically loaded ;)

Comment: That is true of course. By "reference them" I wanted to say "in custom html module use selectors defined in template.css or custom.css, because that styling is automatically loaded". Sorry for my bad English.